# Modify JAXB xs:any attribute processContents using a binding file

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

In a WSDL file, there is an xs:any element that I want to override from:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetPermissionCollectionResult">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

To:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetPermissionCollectionResult">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Ultimately what I'm doing is using JAXB to generate annotated Java code from the WSDL. And for the xs:any element, this is generated:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
```

Instead I want this:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = false)
```

The WSDL file is not generated by me so I can't just make the modification to the file. Is there a way of using a JAXB binding file to get the same effect?

I looked at using jaxb:property and jaxb:class elements but neither seems to fit want I want done.